# How to make a Spherical Joint anchor follow an object

Tags: three.js, rotation, react-three-fiber

I mean by Spherical Joint anchor, is the same as the one is used in [the rapier documentation example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-rapier-joints-mhhbd4) . I mean by an object, a .glTF model that I loaded.

Please check my [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/A7medAbdien/ropee/master?workspaceId=0ee2af4b-9578-434d-a8c8-e340ddc060d9&file=%2Fsrc%2FExperience.jsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A30%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A70%2C%22startColumn%22%3A30%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A70%7D%5D&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cleh7ptz00009g4eveuhdbi0y%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522spaces%2522%253A%257B%2522cleh7pwt4000e356iu6bp5w6y%2522%253A%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522cleh7pwt4000e356iu6bp5w6y%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Default%2522%252C%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cleh7qeoh008u356i9dj03az0%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522currentSpace%2522%253A%2522cleh7pwt4000e356iu6bp5w6y%2522%252C%2522spacesOrder%2522%253A%255B%2522cleh7pwt4000e356iu6bp5w6y%2522%255D%252C%2522hideCodeEditor%2522%253Afalse%257D)

I am trying to make the anchor, Spherical Joint anchor, to follow the edge of the model, when it rotate or moves.

I was able to make the anchor follows the model position using this method, and I call it on each frame

```js
const move = (leftAnchor, rightAnchor) => {

    /**
     *  model: a reference for the group that contain the .glTF model
     *  leftAnchorPos: the initial position of the leftAnchor
     *  rightAnchorPos: the initial position of the rightAnchor
     */
    const modelPos = model.current.position
    const leftPos = new Vector3(
        leftAnchorPos.x + modelPos.x,
        leftAnchorPos.y + modelPos.y,
        leftAnchorPos.z + modelPos.z)
    const rightPos = new Vector3(
        rightAnchorPos.x + modelPos.x,
        rightAnchorPos.y + modelPos.y,
        rightAnchorPos.z + modelPos.z)

    leftAnchor.setNextKinematicTranslation(leftPos)
    rightAnchor.setNextKinematicTranslation(rightPos)

}
```

I am struggling with making the anchor moves in the right position to follow the model rotation. I am wondering if there is an easier way to do that.

Comment: Have you considered adding the anchors as children to your model, and setting just their local positions? This will make them follow the model automatically.

Comment: I can do that? how?

Comment: If you add a child using `Object3D.add()`, then it will follow the parent's transformation. If you add a position to the child object, it will then be relative to parent position, not world origin. So could this be what you need?

Comment: thanks , it works for the scene, but it does not affect the physics world

Comment: I see. Still, you can probably find the world transform of the child to update the physics world, without having to do any maths yourself.

Comment: Should be doable using Three.js' `Object3D.getWorldPosition()`. Unfortunately I don't know react so I cannot help you further, but glad to have been of help so far and good luck :)

Comment: It worked, I added a group as a connector and added it to the model, it made it easier to deal with the react part.  Again thank you @Berthur